Customizing PDF Bookmarks
I was able to successfully add a "Chapter" prefix to my bookmarks when rendered in PDF form using the following code.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\Hy@numberline[1]{Chapter #1: }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Preface}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
    Some text
    \chapter{First chapter}
    More text
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    Even more text
    \section{First section}
    A section header
    \section{Second section}
    Another section header
\end{document}

Kudos to Ulrike Fischer for pointing this out.
The {bookmark} package works well and using the Hy@numberline option helped much.
My question is how would I go about prepending something like "Section" before the \section header in the PDF bookmarks?
Here is how it looks currently. Just want to change the beginning of the /section to reflect the section name. I am guessing I am just missing something obvious.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the URL where Ulrike posted the original answer: Modify numbering style of PDF bookmarks

can you link to where Ulrike suggested this rather than her profile? I already know who she is :-).

Edited comment to reference Ulrike's original post. My bad. I had planned to post that but forgot.

I wouldn't overdo it, too long bookmarks do not look nice.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand\Hy@numberline[1]
 {
   \int_case:nn {\Hy@toclevel}
    {
      {0}{Chapter~}
      {1}{Section~}
      {2}{Subsection~}
    }  
   #1:~ 
 }
 \ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Preface}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
    Some text
    \chapter{First chapter}
    More text
    \chapter{Second chapter}
    Even more text
    \section{First section}
    A section header
    \section{Second section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \subsubsection{subsub}
    Another section header
\end{document}



When should one add the bookmark package, as most of the bookmark code is also incorporated in hyperref.

@yannisl I would always use bookmark and if you use the new tagging code it is loaded by default, it can create the bookmarks directly on the first compilation and has more options.

I agree; too long of bookmarks can be obnoxioous. However, the target audience is requesting this. @UlrikeFischer your feedback is very much appreciated.
